# Handling missing and new fields in tableSchema of BigQuery in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

**Here is the situation:**

My **BigQuery TableSchema** is as follows:

```
  {
    "name": "Id",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "nullable"
  },
  {
    "name": "Address",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "repeated",
    "fields":[
      {
        "name": "Street",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "nullable"
      },
      {
        "name": "City",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "nullable"
      }
     ]
   }
```

I am reading data from a Google Cloud Storage Bucket and writing in to BigQuery using a cloud function.

**I have defined TableSchema in my cloud function as**:

```
table_schema = bigquery.TableSchema()

Id_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
Id_schema.name = 'Id'
Id_schema.type = 'INTEGER'
Id_schema.mode = 'nullable'
table_schema.fields.append(Id_schema)

Address_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
Address_schema.name = 'Address'
Address_schema.type = 'RECORD'
Address_schema.mode = 'repeated'

Street_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
Street_schema.name = 'Street'
Street_schema.type = 'STRING'
Street_schema.mode = 'nullable'
Address_schema.fields.append(Street_schema)
table_schema.fields.append(Address_schema)

City_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
City_schema.name = 'City'
City_schema.type = 'STRING'
City_schema.mode = 'nullable'
Address_schema.fields.append(City_schema)
table_schema.fields.append(Address_schema)
```

**My data file looks like this:** (each row is json)

```
{"Id": 1, "Address": {"Street":"MG Road","City":"Pune"}}
{"Id": 2, "Address": {"City":"Mumbai"}}
{"Id": 3, "Address": {"Street":"XYZ Road"}}
{"Id": 4}
{"Id": 5, "PhoneNumber": 12345678, "Address": {"Street":"ABCD Road", "City":"Bangalore"}}
```

**Question**:
How can I handle when the incoming data has some missing keys? 
e.g.,

- On row #2 of the data `"Street"` is missing
- On row #3 of the data `"City"` is missing
- On row #4 of the data `"Address"` is missing
- On row #5 of the data `"PhoneNumber"` shows up..

**Question 1**: How to handle `WriteToBigQuery` if the data in missing (e.g., row #2,#3,#4)

**Question 2**: How to handle if a new field shows up in the data? 
e.g.,

- On row #5 `"PhoneNumber"` shows up..
  How can I add a new column in BigQuery table on the fly? 
  (Do I have have to define the BigQuery table schema exhaustive enough at first in order to accommodate such newly added fields?)

**Question 3**: How can I iterate through each row (while reading data file) of the incoming data file and determine which fields to parse?

Comment: Preetesh, have you gotten the response that you need? Or do you still need help?

Comment: Pablo, Thank you for asking. I still need help. I was not able to successfully able to decode JSON string into data structure logic where I can access and manipulate which values are optional and which are required over the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: How can I handle when the incoming data has some missing keys?
>
> **Question 1**: How to handle WriteToBigQuery if the data in missing (e.g., row #2,#3,#4)
>
> **Question 2**: How to handle if a new field shows up in the data?

I recommend decoding the JSON string to some data structure, for example a custom `Contact` class, where you can access and manipulate member variables and define which members are optional and which are required. Using a custom class gives you a level of abstraction so that downstream transforms in the pipeline don't need to worry about how to manipulate JSON. A downstream transform can be implemented to build a `TableRow` from a `Contact` object and also adhere to the BigQuery table schema. This design follows general abstraction and separation of concerns principles and is able to handle all scenarios of missing or additional fields.

> **Question 3**: How can I iterate through each row (while reading data file) of the incoming data file and determine which fields to parse?

Dataflow's execution of the pipeline does this automatically. If the pipeline reads from Google Cloud Storage (using `TextIO` for example), then Dataflow will process each line of the file as an individual element (individual JSON string). Determining which fields to parse is a detail of the business logic and can be defined in a transform which parses the JSON string.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! Can you please update with the code/implementation so I can try to replicate in my local.

Answer (score 2):

One of the option for you is  - instead of straggling with schema changes I would recommend to write your data into table with just one field `line` of type `string` - and apply schema logic on fly during the querying

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL of how to apply schema on fly against table with whole row in one field

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT '{"Id": 1, "Address": {"Street":"MG Road","City":"Pune"}}' line UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"Id": 2, "Address": {"City":"Mumbai"}}' UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"Id": 3, "Address": {"Street":"XYZ Road"}}' UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"Id": 4}  ' UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"Id": 5, "PhoneNumber": 12345678, "Address": {"Street":"ABCD Road", "City":"Bangalore"}}' 
)
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(line, '$.Id') id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(line, '$.PhoneNumber') PhoneNumber,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(line, '$[Address].Street') Street,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(line, '$[Address].City') City 
FROM t
```

with result as below

```sql
Row id  PhoneNumber Street      City     
1   1   null        MG Road     Pune     
2   2   null        null        Mumbai   
3   3   null        XYZ Road    null     
4   4   null        null        null     
5   5   12345678    ABCD Road   Bangalore
```

I think this approach answers/addresses all your four questions

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! I will try this. How to write data into table with just one field `line` of type `string`, given that the data file has `n` number of rows?

Comment: Just define schema of table to have one field so whole row will be loaded as one field. Each row I file will become row in table

Comment: Tried doing that. Getting `Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1., error: Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1., error: Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Value encountered without start of object.`

Comment: How to write data to BigQuery as each row being single field named `line` and type `STRING` given the current input data set?